# create a constraint between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql and have not have much experience in it

Trying to create a relationship between two tables using a constraint.

adding a unique constraint and relationship for force the `userid` and `consumerid` between `table1` and `table2`

any sample will help me

Thanks

Comment: This question lacks the kinds of details needed for others to really help. Table samples, data samples and a clear explanation would help considerably.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `FOREIGN KEY (blabla) REFERENCES secondTable(blabla)` but only if the table is not created yet. Write it inside your CREATE TABLE query.
But if it already exists you can add it using `` ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_myKey` FOREIGN KEY (`blabla`) REFERENCES `secondTable` (`blabla`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE; ``

Comment: do i need to add the cascades

Comment: in this the tablename will be table2

Comment: @TreeNode yes i just wrote the idea and you should at least be able to rewrite it. Yes you need to add cascades, because once a value is deleted from the second table it should be automatically removed from the first table and thats actually what CASCADE does.